# How to retrieve unique column value from a oracle table object

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a oracle table type object and want to retrieve only unique values from specific column without looping using index.

For example i would want to achieve with something like this.

```
 SELECT SET (NUMBER_TBL.S_NO)
   INTO NumbersTab
   FROM dual;
```

Comment: @APC, Please read the question, "I have a oracle table type object and want to retrieve only unique values from specific column". Not sure why would you need type and structure. I'm basically looking at select distinct column from table_name equivalent.

Comment: @RamKumar It would assist making your question more comprehensible if you gave the DDL statements that defined the object type and the table type for that object and an example of what input you have into your query and what output you would expect.

Comment: At the moment your question requires us to **guess** what you're trying to achieve. It seems MT0 is the gambling kind, and has built a nice little demo of a potential solution. But all that code they posted as **Oracle Setup**? That's the code you should have included in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extract the column from the object type and then re-aggregate into a collection of a simple type and then you can use the `SET()` function:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE NUMBER_OBJ AS OBJECT( s_no NUMBER )
/
CREATE TYPE NUMBER_TBL AS TABLE OF NUMBER_OBJ
/
CREATE TYPE number_list AS TABLE OF NUMBER
/

CREATE TABLE test_data ( numbers NUMBER_TBL )
NESTED TABLE numbers STORE AS test_data__numbers
/
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test_data
  VALUES (
    NUMBER_TBL(
      NUMBER_OBJ( 1 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 1 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 2 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 3 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 3 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 4 )
    )
  );

  INSERT INTO test_data
  VALUES (
    NUMBER_TBL(
      NUMBER_OBJ( 5 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 5 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 5 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 6 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 6 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 5 )
    )
  );
END;
/
```

**SQL Query**:

```sql
SELECT SET( CAST( COLLECT( n.s_no ORDER BY n.s_no ) AS number_list ) )
FROM   test_data t
       CROSS JOIN TABLE( t.numbers ) n
GROUP BY t.rowid
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | SET(CAST(COLLECT(N.S_NOORDERBYN.S_NO)ASNUMBER_LIST)) |
> |------------------------------------------------------|
> |                                              1,2,3,4 |
> |                                                  5,6 |
> ```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f9e73/2/0)

**PL/SQL Option 1 - `SET`**

```sql
DECLARE
  n_tbl NUMBER_TBL := NUMBER_TBL(
      NUMBER_OBJ( 1 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 1 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 2 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 3 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 3 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 4 )
    );
  NumbersTab number_list;
BEGIN
  SELECT SET(
           CAST(
             COLLECT( s_no ORDER BY s_no )
             AS number_list
           )
         )
  INTO   NumbersTab
  FROM   TABLE( n_tbl );

  FOR i IN 1 .. NumbersTab.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( NumbersTab(i) || ',' );
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '' );
END;
/
```

**PL/SQL Option 2 - No SQL using `SET`**:

```sql
DECLARE
  n_tbl NUMBER_TBL := NUMBER_TBL(
      NUMBER_OBJ( 1 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 1 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 2 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 3 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 3 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 4 )
    );
  NumbersTab number_list;
BEGIN
  NumbersTab := number_list();
  NumbersTab.EXTEND( n_tbl.COUNT );
  FOR i IN 1 .. n_tbl.COUNT LOOP
    NumbersTab(i) := n_tbl(i).s_no;
  END LOOP;
  NumbersTab := SET( NumbersTab );

  FOR i IN 1 .. NumbersTab.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( NumbersTab(i) || ',' );
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '' );
END;
/
```

**PL/SQL Option 3 - `BULK COLLECT INTO`**:

```sql
DECLARE
  n_tbl NUMBER_TBL := NUMBER_TBL(
      NUMBER_OBJ( 1 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 1 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 2 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 3 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 3 ),
      NUMBER_OBJ( 4 )
    );
  NumbersTab number_list;
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT s_no
  BULK COLLECT INTO NumbersTab
  FROM   TABLE( n_tbl )
  ORDER BY s_no;

  FOR i IN 1 .. NumbersTab.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( NumbersTab(i) || ',' );
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '' );
END;
/
```

all output:

> ```
> 1,2,3,4,
> ```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=194585622f3746e73fb0a78ab568bac7)

Comment: Option 3 is exactly what i wanted. Appreciate your efforts on this, i should have been more specific with the question.

Comment: @RamKumar All 3 PL/SQL options should give the same result. Option 2 may end up being faster as there is no context switch from PL/SQL to SQL (which does occur in options 1 & 3) however that is not guaranteed as the collection may end up being copied when `SET()` is invoked. You would need to profile the different options and see which works best for your database.